# Is there any function in Contiki similar to clock_gettime() from time.h?

Tags: c, contiki

I want to use a function similar to the `clock_gettime()` function from `time.h` to calculate the time taken in a function call. I to include `time.h`, but found that it does not exist in Contiki.

Comment: Try clock() and use your CPU frequency to calculate the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the rtimer functions for this task. The clock module is not suitable, as it's not meant for real-time or high-precision time accounting.

```
rtimer_clock_t start;
start = RTIMER_NOW();
/* ...do stuff... */
printf("it took %u ticks to do stuff\n", RTIMER_NOW() - start);
```

The typical duration a rtimer tick is 1/32768 seconds. If you need even greater precision, you're left with hardware-specific counters.